# Why does my function return None everytime it is called even though it has a return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, return

I am learning classes in Python and here is a code I have written

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hour, minute):
        self.hour=hour
        self.minute=minute

    def displayTime(self):
        return f"{self.hour} hours and {self.minute} minutes" 

    def addTime(self, s):
        temp = Time(0,0)
        temp.minute = self.minute + s.minute
        temp.hour = self.hour + s.hour
        if temp.minute>=60:
            temp.hour+=1
            temp.minute-=60
        temp.displayTime()

if __name__=='__main__':
    t1= Time(12,50)
    t2 = Time(11,36)

    print(t1.displayTime())
    print(t2.displayTime())

    print(t1.addTime(t2))
```

But when I run it, the last print statement prints `None`. But if I change `return` in `displayTime` to `print`, it prints the time correctly.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should add `return temp.displayTime()` in `addTime` method last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer as soon as I posted it. For future reference to others, I am posting the answer here.

In function `addTime`, I called the function `displayTime`

```
def addTime(self, s):
    ...
   temp.displayTime()
```

The function displayTime returns the value to the function `addTime`, while `addTime` does not return anything. Hence, it prints `None`.

To correct it, I just have to return displayTime

```
def addTime(self, s):
    ...
   return temp.displayTime()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def addTime(self, s):
    temp = Time(0,0)
    temp.minute = self.minute + s.minute
    temp.hour = self.hour + s.hour
    if temp.minute>=60:
        temp.hour+=1
        temp.minute-=60
    return temp.displayTime()  # <- this is the issue.
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I got the answer as soon as I posted the question and have also written an answer here. But still, thanks a lot for answering.